# How to stop video when press back button in Android

Tags: android, video, android-webview, android-websettings

I want show video in `WebView`, and for this i want use this code :

```
    WebSettings settings = post_content_web.getSettings();
    post_content_web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

    post_content_web.loadDataWithBaseURL("", myCustomStyleString + "<div style=\"direction:rtl\">"
            + title + "\n\n" + content + "</div>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

With above codes i can show video but when video is playing and when click on `BackPressButton` not **stop** this video and video play! 
I want when click on `BackButton` stop this video!

How can i it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        post_content_web.loadUrl("about:blank");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    webview.destroy();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

While Nouri's answer works exactly as the OP wants, for many you may want to stop video playback when a Fragment has been replaced or hidden--not just when the back button is pressed.

The solution is the same, but I recommend putting the code in `onPause()`.  This will cover the above situations *and* the back button at the same time.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    post_content_web.loadUrl("about:blank");    // Stop video playback
}
```